# Show the percentage of Download files in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, download, file-transfer

i  am using cordova 3.5 for create a app for ipad ios.
now I can download files from the server, but i want to show the percentage of the "Download".
some sample example?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using file transfer plugin to download http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Here is the onProgress method

```
var fileTransfer= new FileTransfer();

fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    var percent =  progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100;
    percent = Math.round(percent);
    console.log(percent);
};

//fileTransfer.download(...); // or fileTransfer.upload(...);
```